# Proof of one point set in general topology is closed

Tags: general-topology

How can I prove one point set in general topology is closed? 
There is a guide that "$\mathbb R$ with general topology is a $T_2$ space, so that an open set is closed", but I can't understand that. Can you clarify it for me?

Comment: What is this guide which says an open set in a $T_2$ space is closed?  Please give a reference, since it seems you must have misunderstood it it.

Comment: Spaces in which all one-point sets are closed are exactly $T_1$ spaces, and all $T_2$ spaces are also $T_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the statements separately: a space $X$ is called $T_2$ or *Hausdorff* when

> for all $x,y \in X$ with $x \neq y$ we have two open sets $O_x$ and $O_y$ such that $$x \in O_x, y \in O_y, O_x \cap O_y = \emptyset\text{.}$$

or, in words, distinct points in $X$ can be separated by open sets.

$\Bbb R$ in its usual topology, is indeed Hausdorff: when we view it as an ordered space, for $x \neq y$, say $x < y$, we pick any $z \in \Bbb R$ such that $x < z < y$ and then $O_x = \{u \in \Bbb R: u < z\}$ and $O_y = \{u \in \Bbb R: u > z\}$ are open by the definition of the order topology and are as required.

When we view it as a metric space, it's also easy to see: If $x \neq y$ in the metric space $(X,d)$, then set $r=\frac{d(x,y)}{2}>0$ and note that $O_x=B(x,r)$ and $O_y=B(y,r)$ are open by the definition of the metric topology and disjoint (otherwise some $z \in B(x,r) \cap B(y,r)$ implies that $$d(x,y) \le d(x,z) + d(z,y) < r+r = 2r= d(x,y)$$ a contradiction)

So we've established that $\Bbb R$ is Hausdorff.

In a Hausdorff space all sets of the form $\{p\}$ are closed: if $x \neq p$ then $O_x$ from the definition of Hausdorffness applied to $x$ and $p$ is such that $p \notin O_x$, so $O_x \subseteq X\setminus \{p\}$ and so

$$X\setminus \{p\} = \bigcup \{O_x: x \in X\setminus \{p\}\}$$

is open as a union of open sets.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to show that $\{x\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology.

This follows since $\mathbb R\smallsetminus \{x\}$ is open. Indeed, given $y\in\mathbb R\smallsetminus \{x\}$, then the open ball $B(y,\frac{|x-y|}2)\subseteq \mathbb R\smallsetminus \{x\}$.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are talking about the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ considering there are topologies under which singletons are open. If you take $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology the complement of a singleton $\{x\}$ is $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{x\}$. So now you want to show that $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{x\}$ is open in order to show that $\{x\}$ is closed. So if you consider $$\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-\infty, x - \frac{1}{n})\cup(x + \frac{1}{n}, \infty)=\mathbb{R} \setminus \{x\}$$
which are all open sets then you get the desired result. The key to determining if a set is closed is to showing that its complement is open.